# Refreshing <div> in django but auto refreshing the whole template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, refresh

I'm adding objects to my model using a POST request from a Wi-Fi module. It stores data from different sensors. The data is sent periodically after every 5 seconds. To display those data, I've created a page. I don't want the whole page to refresh because different divs get data at different time. What I want to achieve is, certain divs to refresh periodically, say 10 secs, and get the updated data.

I created a test template to test the auto-refresh part.
So far I've achieved this:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^test/', views.test, name='test'),
]
```

views.py:

```
def test(request):
    acc_list = AccModel.objects.order_by('-updated')[:10]
    gps_list = GpsModel.objects.order_by('-updated')[:1]
    obj_dict = {'accVal': acc_list, 'gpsVal': gps_list}
    return render(request, 'appTwo/test.html', context=obj_dict)
```

template file(test.html):(I want to auto-refresh just the div with id="test")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function refresh() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url 'test' %}',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#test').replaceWith($('#test', data));
                }
            });

        }

        $(function () {
            setInterval('refresh()', 10000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
{% if accVal %}
    <h1>{{ accVal }}</h1>
{% endif %}
{% if gpsVal %}
    <div id="test">
        <h1>{{ gpsVal.0.latValue }}</h1>
    </div>
{% endif %}

<div>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
    <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyApiKey&callback=initMap">
    </script>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    gmaps js..
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> When I run the above code, the "test"div disappears after the first
>   auto-refresh.

I have tried these also:

just posting the js part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'test' %}",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#test').replaceWith($('#test',data)); // NOTE this
        }
    });
}
var seconds = 3; // seconds, edit here
setInterval(refresh(),seconds * 1000);
    </script>
```

I get two GET request, and the "test"div disappears in a fraction of second.

The closest I got is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function refresh() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url 'test' %}',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#test').replaceWith($('#test'), data);
                }
            });

        }

        $(function () {
            setInterval('refresh()', 10000);
        });
    </script>
```

> In this, I get "GET" request every 10 seconds. and the "test"div also
>   doesn't disappear. But, even if the value in the model object is
>   changed, the value remains same here.

Comment: By using `$(...)` you actually immediately refresh once the document is loaded. The `setTimeout(refresh, 10000)` should be called outside to give it a certain delay.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My bad!! Thanks for the correction! Got it right now :)

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't it the problem with urls? I mean the ajax is calling the url which renders my complete view. If that's true, how to get the url of that particular div with id='test'?

Answer (score 0):

[`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) will do the trick, refresh the page continuously after a specific time.
To replace the target div, use `replaceWith()`

```
function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'test' %}",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#test').replaceWith($('#test',data)); // NOTE this
        }
    });
}
var seconds = 3; // seconds, edit here
setInterval(refresh(),seconds * 1000);
```